# JQGrid: Perfomace of view when load all data?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid view in [.net] web app. This view use for print function, i want use print function of Browser standart => NEED load all data to jqgrid view.

Data size is 10.000 items with 10 columns.

```
What's time jqgrid  can load all data and how to increase performance of this view ????
```

Comment: Is the view only used for printing? If users usually just view it and sometimes print, you may consider paging for standard view and a less performant view just for printing. Also, I doubt the users need all the other full fledged features of a grid when printing. Just a suggestion if you find you cannot make the grid perform well enough.

Comment: Yes, user want to print all content of this view. Suggest to me...